# Want to delete class of inner div when outside div and inner div having same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="test">
  <div class="test">
    <div class="test">
       Test Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to remove class test of inner div. I am able do to it with code below, but looking for more generic method for n level. Please guide me right way to achieve this.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    // this will delete class test of level 1
    $($(".test")[1]).removeClass('test');
    //or
    // this will delete class test of level 2
    $($(".test")[2]).removeClass('test');
  });
</script>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1xwafowr/)

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1xwafowr/3/) still not working.

Thanks

Comment: Try with `$(".test .test").removeClass('test');` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(function() {
  $("div.test > div.test").removeClass("test");
});
```

It gets a `div` with class `test` which is a direct descendant of another `div` with class `test`, and removes its class.

You can also make it a function:

```
function removeDuplicateClass(cls) {
    return $("div." + cls + " > div." + cls).removeClass(cls).length;
}
```

EDIT: after seeing the edit, this should work

```
function removeDuplicateClass(cls, level) {
  // get all top level divs with that class
  var parent = $("div." + cls).filter(function () {
    return !$(this).parent().is("div." + cls);
  });

  // build selector
  var selector = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < level; ++i) {
    selector.push("> div." + cls);
  }

  // now remove class
  return $(selector.join(" "), parent).removeClass(cls).length;
}
```

Comment: it will remove class from all nested div. Sorry if my question not clear. I want to pass level as number of which div I want to delete class. In the above case level will be 1. Suppose I have 3 level and I pass level 2 it should delete class test of level 2 only..

Comment: Please try to setup a jsFiddle with a test case